# Oracle pro*c way to query DB for difference of array values and DB column values

Tags: c++, sql, c, oracle, embedded-sql

I have c/c++ code with embedded SQL for Oracle through Pro*C. Is there any mechanism to get the difference of values of array values and DB column values? For example, say, I have an array like this:

```
int nums[] = {10,20,35,45};
vector<int> vnums (nums, nums + sizeof(nums) / sizeof(int) );
```

Now, I have a DB table `tbl1` with `col1` containing values:

```
20
40
60
```

I would like to get the unmatched array values that are not present in `tbl1`.
So, result should be:

```
10
35
45
```

I know one way. I may run the following SQL query:

```
select col1 from tab1
```

And store the results in an vector say, `vec2`.
Now, I see the difference of these two vectors vnums and vec2.
Can you suggest a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to directly do that and your approach is fine.

What you can do is to wrap the call to the DB with a stream and create a procedure which loading your input values in using something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE numArray_t AS TABLE OF NUMBER
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION extractDif (p_data IN numArray_t) return numArray_t;
```

and in the function you will perform a `MINUS` of the passed `numArray_t` with the values from your table and stream the differences.